# How can I force /dev/random to block?

Tags: linux-kernel, random, cryptography

For a class on cryptography, I am trying to drain the entropy pool in Linux (e.g. make `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` go to 0 and block a command reading from `/dev/random`) but I can't make it happen. I'm supposed to get reads from `/dev/random` to block. If I execute these two commands:

```
watch -n 0.5 cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

to watch entropy and then:

```
od -d /dev/random
```

to dump the random pool, the value from the `watch` command hovers between 3700 and 3900, and gains and loses only a little while I run this command. I let both commands run for about three minutes with no discernible substantial change in the size of `entropy_avail`. I didn't do much on the computer during that time. From googling around I find that perhaps a hardware random number generator could be so good that the entropy won't drop but if I do:

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/misc/hw_random/rng_available
```

I see nothing, I just get a blank line. So I have a few questions:

1. What's replenishing my entropy so well, and how can I find the specific source of randomness?
2. Is there any way to temporarily disable sources of randomness so I can force this blocking to happen?

Comment: For recent kernels, ["/dev/random will still block just after booting"](https://lwn.net/Articles/808575/).

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this? You said it was for a class, but what exactly is the goal?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a surprising amount of development going on around the Linux random device. The slow, blocking `/dev/random` is gone and replaced by a fast `/dev/random` that never runs out of data.

You'll have to travel back in time, like prior to linux 4.8 ([which introduced a much faster crng algorithm](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/e192be9d9a30555aae2ca1dc3aad37cba484cd4a)) or possibly linux 5.6 ([which introduced jitter entropy generation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3f2dc2798b81531fd93a3b9b7c39da47ec689e55)).

There is no way to get the original behavior back in current kernels.

---

If you are seeing this issue in older versions of Linux, hwrng aside, you might be using `haveged` or rng-tools `rngd`, or similar userspace entropy providers.

Some distros install these by default to avoid hangs while waiting for a few random bits, in that case you can uninstall or disable them or try it from within an initrd / busybox shell where no other processes are running.

If the issue still persists, you might just have a very noisy piece of hardware from which kernel keeps collecting entropy naturally.

Answer (score 21):

> What's replenishing my entropy so well, and how can I find the specific source of randomness?

As of kernel 5.6, `/dev/random` obtains randomness from the kernel's CRNG, which is initialized during boot and does not block.

See ["Removing the Linux /dev/random blocking pool"](https://lwn.net/Articles/808575/).

> Is there any way to temporarily disable sources of randomness so I can force this blocking to happen?

I think you would have to use a pre-5.6 kernel.

Answer (score 5):

This can depend on your hardware if it's using the CPU features then it might be endless. Other hardware is not.

However, you could try the [kernel option](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) `random.trust_cpu=off` when booting.